# replacing characters in a string

Tags: javascript

Why does this just not work out for me ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gene="ATTAHATHHATTCGTA";
var i=0;
for (;i<gene.lenth;i++)
{
   if(gene[i]=='H')
     gene[i]='G';
}
</script>
```

I change it by use of replace as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gene="ATTAHATHHATTCGTA";
var i=0;
for (;i<gene.lenth;)
{
   var pos=gene.replace("H","G");
   i+=pos;
}
</script>
```

but I am still out of luck. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is used much more simply:

```
var gene="ATTAHATHHATTCGTA"; 
gene = gene.replace("H", "G", "g"); // The last "g" means "replace all occurrences"
```

Simple as that.

However, this is not going to work on all browsers. To make it portable, you have to specify the first parameter as a regular expression, like this:

```
var gene="ATTAHATHHATTCGTA"; 
gene = gene.replace(/H/g, "G"); // The /g means "replace all occurrences"
```

Comment: And there is a spelling mistake:

"for (;i<gene.lenth;)"

should be

"for (;i<gene.length;)"

Comment: @Mackintoast: Please check out the edit I just saved though, regarding the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Both function have the `.length` property misspelled as `.lenth`. But aside from that...

The reason your first function doesn't work is because not all browsers support array-style index access to individual characters in strings, and even for the ones that do [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) they only support *read* access.

The reason the second function doesn't work is because when you pass a string to `.replace()` it will only replace the first instance and putting it in a loop doesn't help with that.

You can easily achieve the same thing using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as the first parameter to the [.replace() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), where use of a regex lets you specify additional parameters such as a global replace (or you can make it a case insensitve replace):

```
gene = gene.replace(/H/g, "G");
```

If for some reason you really want to process the string yourself going character by character you can easily turn it into an array with the [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split), and then when you're finished turn it back into a string with the [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var gene="ATTAHATHHATTCGTA",
    i,
    geneArray = gene.split("");

for (i=0;i<geneArray.length;i++)
{
   if(geneArray[i]=='H')
     geneArray[i]='G';
}
gene = geneArray.join("");
```

(Obviously you wouldn't do it that way when `.replace()` can do it for you, but that's just an example.)